# How to open atoti link in streamlit application with python?

Tags: html, pandas, dataframe, streamlit, atoti

I'm trying to run atoti link in streamlit application where i want to create some plots with atoti.
I tried the below code but it's showing something else in place of the link.

```
new = pd.DataFrame()
new['Link'] = [session.link()]
st.dataframe(new)
st.write(new.to_html(escape=False, index=False), unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

The output is

```
     Link
    
 0   Link(_path='', _session=<atoti.session.Session object at 0x000002B700293FA0>)
```

Followed by :

```
Link

Link(_path='', _session=)
```

The expected link is http://localhost:53533

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented [here](https://docs.atoti.io/0.6.1/lib/atoti.session.html#atoti.session.Session.link), `Session.link()` is only available in JupyterLab.

You could use `f"http://localhost:{session.port}"`.

[It's also possible to always use the same port](https://docs.atoti.io/0.6.1/lib/atoti.config.session_config.html#atoti.config.session_config.SessionConfig.port).